# How do I send a POST request to Spring Boot from terminal?

Tags: bash, http, terminal

A Spring Boot service running at `localhost:7090/someurl` accepts parameters `Var1` and `Var2` in `POST` requests. How can I test this from the CentOS 7 terminal?

When I type `localhost:7090/someurl?Var1=something&Var2=anotherthing` into the web browser, the logs show that an unsuported `GET` request was made.  How do I mimmick a `POST` request to test this service?  What do I type into the CentOS 7 terminal?

Comment: You may find a browser tool like Postman more intuitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if it is a normal bash shell, you can always use curl (you maybe need to install it), for example:

```
curl -X POST -d "Var1=VALUE1&Var2=VALUE2" localhost:7090/someurl
```

Comment: Thank you and +1 for a concise and prompt reply.